# Jest: Restoring Implementation of function prevents Remocking

Tags: jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

This is my situation:

In Describe Block 1:

1. I spy on a function (bulkUpsert)
2. I mock its implementation
3. Restore its implementation

In Describe Block 2:

1. I spy on the same function (bulkUpsert)
2. I mock its implementation (doesn't work)

The tests in my second describe block fail because the implementation was never remocked.

More specifically, I have

```
describe('BulkUpsert Fail Error Handling', () => {
  const orderRepositorySpy = jest.spyOn(OrderRepository, 'bulkUpsert');
  beforeAll(() => {
    orderRepositorySpy.mockImplementationOnce(async () => {
      await Promise.reject('Some Error that does not matter');
    });
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    parseJsonlFileSpy.mockReset();
    orderRepositorySpy.mockRestore();
  });

it('......')
}
```

Then

```
describe('Batching', () => {
  const orderRepositorySpy = jest.spyOn(OrderRepository, 'bulkUpsert');
  beforeAll(async () => {
    orderRepositorySpy.mockImplementation(async () => {
      await Promise.resolve();
    });
    await request.post('/').send({ accountId, url });
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    orderRepositorySpy.mockRestore();
  });

  it('BulkUpsert is called on Orders 3 Times', () => {
    expect(orderRepositorySpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
  });

});
```

The 'BulkUpsert is called on Orders 3 Times' fails. This is strange because

1. I stepped through the code (jest watch current file), and I saw bulkUpsert being called 3 times
2. I saw that bulkUpsert was actually adding records to the DB ---> I.e, the implementation was never mocked in the second describe block

To get tests to pass, I had to use mockReset. But that was problematic because I actually have describe blocks (in between the two mentioned above) that rely on the original implementation.

Sure, I can change the order of describe blocks around, but I want to understand why this is not working.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot about javascript hoisting.

```
describe('BulkUpsert Fail Error Handling', () => {
  let orderRepositorySpy;
  beforeAll(() => {
    orderRepositorySpy =  = jest.spyOn(OrderRepository, 'bulkUpsert');
    orderRepositorySpy.mockImplementationOnce(async () => {
      await Promise.reject('Some Error that does not matter');
    });
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    parseJsonlFileSpy.mockReset();
    orderRepositorySpy.mockRestore();
  });

it('......')
}
```

```
describe('Batching', () => {
  let orderRepositorySpy;
  beforeAll(async () => {
    orderRepositorySpy = jest.spyOn(OrderRepository, 'bulkUpsert');
    orderRepositorySpy.mockImplementation(async () => {
      await Promise.resolve();
    });
    await request.post('/').send({ accountId, url });
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    orderRepositorySpy.mockRestore();
  });

  it('BulkUpsert is called on Orders 3 Times', () => {
    expect(orderRepositorySpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
  });

});
```